# How to remove the special characters when getting the data using json in android?

Tags: android, json

I am working on android application. I need to get the data from PHP web service. The response which I am getting from PHP server is shown below:

```
String response = [{id:100,category:local,count1:58,count2:86},
    {id:101,category:server/local,count1:18,count2:27},
    {id:102,category:server & local,count1:19,count2:28}];
```

But I am getting the following message when I am trying to separate the data using JSON.

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character
```

How to remove special characters and get the data using JSON array?

Comment: Use replace function to remove special char.

Comment: which character is throwing that exception?

Comment: That is not a valid JSON String

Comment: @User1448108 Vamshi is right its not a valid JSON response.

Comment: In fact it is neither a correct java sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Strings should be under double quotes. Your json is not a valid response. So change your response from

```
{id:100,category:local,count1:58,count2:86}
```

to

```
{
 "id":100,
 "category":"local",
 "count1":58,
 "count2":86
}
```

Refer [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Yes, but we can add 100, 58 and 86 as integers, no need of double quote

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON format

```
{
   "Status":"OK",
   "Error":{
      "Code":0,
      "Description":""
   },
   "Data":[]
}
```